# Absense of js animation affects css gradient

Tags: javascript, css, gradient, background-color

I was experimenting with CSS gradients to get familiar with them. It might sound silly but I tried to apply 'opacity' using `.animate()` in javascript (just trying things out!), and some linear-gradient to text using CSS.

[image: First]

But as soon as I decide to remove the script, the linear-gradient no longer works.

[image: Second]

Why is it behaving like so? How can I fix it?

```js
document.querySelector(".title").animate([
    { opacity: 0 },
    { opacity: 1 }
], { opacity: 0, duration: 500, easing: "ease-in", fill: "forwards" } )
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

/************************** TITLE SECTION ****************************/
.container {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5% auto auto;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 90px;
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, #fdbcac 25%, #3167fa 60%, #fdbcac 100%);
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

/*************************** BACKGROUNDS & IMAGES ********************************/
.top-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.top-background1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- FONTS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- TITLE SECTION -->
  <section class="container-fluid container">
    <img class="top-background" src="images\background.png" />
    <img class="top-background1" src="images\geordanna-cordero-2.jpg" />
    <h1 class="title">
      Sapinder Pal
    </h1>


  </section>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Can you show the problem in a runnable snippet here? Try [reading this on how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Richard I've added the code snippet. plz help me figure out the issue.

Comment: I still can't produce the problem. When I delete the JS, the gradient works the same.

Comment: I'm confused because it works on codepen when I checked now, but still doesn't in my browser. I've tried it in Firefox and the new Edge Chromium

Comment: Yes, I can't see the problem unfortunately ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider browser references and prefixes like `-webkit-` or `-moz-`.

[Browser support reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)

This usually can be the reason why something isn't working right.

Also try out this [text gradient guide](https://cssgradient.io/blog/css-gradient-text/). It may help you with what you are teying to achieve.

Hope this helps. You may not need to worry about JS.

Comment: "-moz-" worked. but I think I had read somewhere that such vendor prefixes are deprecated now?

Comment: @Sapinder not entirely sure if they were or not. However you can look at the list attached to see what CSS properties work with each browser version, and using that vendor prefix (for now) is a fix you can use if you start having any issues.